# vbscript Could not locate automation class

Tags: vbscript

I have to make this vbs script to interface with our ftp server, when i run the script of the test server it runs, but when i run it on my pc it gives

```
Could not locate automation class...
```

I imagine this has something to do with the fact that the server runs windows 2003 where as mine is windows 7 and has all the net frameworks installed and is running aspx pages.

so my question is how do I resolve such that my pc can run vbs com objects?

Maybe registering the com object?? but how would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The COM object does need to be installed and registered on your PC. If it is already installed, you can try to locate the file `SFTPCOMInterface.dll` and then run `regsvr32 [pathToFile]\SFTPCOMInterface.dll`.

However, I'd assume that the file would have been registered during the installation so is it possible that you've not installed the COM object on your local PC? I assume the product you're trying to automate is `EFT Server` so you'd need to install it on your local PC for you to be able to do so. Be careful about licensing though. Assuming you just want to run the scripts on your pc while developing, it might be worth contacting GlobalScape and asking if you're allowed to install it on your local PC for development purposes only etc.